# openssl_public_decrypt returns false but cannot get error message

Tags: php, openssl

I'm trying to decode a string that was encoded with `RSA` private key at an Android device (as some kind of digital signature). I think I have a problem with my `public key` at server side.

```
if (openssl_public_decrypt($token, $decrypted, $pubKey) == FALSE)
{
    while ($msg = openssl_error_string())
    {
        echo "ERROR: " . $msg; 
    }

    return;
}
```

The function `openssl_public_decrypt()` returns false but `openssl_error_string()` does not return any errors. How can I find out what is going wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

This is how I create the encoded value in Android:

```
public static String Sign(byte[] text, RSAPrivateKey privateKey) throws Exception
{
    // Encode the original data with RSA private key
    byte[] encodedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        encodedBytes = c.doFinal(text);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("RSAHelper", "RSA encryption error");
        throw e;
    }

    return Base64.encodeToString(encodedBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really find out why `openssl_error_string()` returns nothing but I could solve my problem with the not accepted `PublicKey`

Since the key-pair had been created by `Android` it could not be directly used by `PHP`. The following problems needed to be solved:

- Missing header and footer
- Wrong line breaks

```
// remove existing line breaks
$pubKey = str_replace ("\r\n" , "" , $pubKey);
$pubKey = str_replace ("\r" , "" , $pubKey);
$pubKey = str_replace ("\n" , "" , $pubKey);

// insert line breaks as expexted by PHP function
$pubKey = wordwrap($pubKey, 65, "\n", true);

// add header and footer
$pubKeyWithHeader = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- \r\n" . $pubKey 
             . " \r\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";

// decode the key
openssl_pkey_get_public($pubKeyWithHeader);
if ($x == FALSE)
{
    echo "error";
    return;
}

// decrypt the message with the public key
if (openssl_public_decrypt($token, $decrypted, $pubKeyWithHeader) == FALSE)
{
    echo "error";
    return;
}

echo $decrypted;
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to decode a string that was encoded with RSA private key at an Android device (as some kind of digital signature)

If its a digital signature, then the padding scheme is different. RSA encryption uses Type 2 padding, while RSA signatures uses Type 1 padding.

Since you believe its a digital signature, you should probably look for a `openssl_public_verify` function (or similar).

Comment: Added the encoding at Android side to my question